# How to find when a transition has finished

Tags: transform, transition, dart

I've been playing with the code from [this website](http://www.gwtsushi.info/2012/08/css3-transitions-and-transforms-with.html)

And now what I'm wanting to do is listen for when a transition has completed so that I can start another transition in sequence.  For example...

```
import "dart:html";

num rotatePos = 0;

void main() {
  query("#buttonRotate").onClick.listen(rotateElement);
}

void rotateElement(Event e) {
  rotatePos += 360;
  Element element = e.target;

  element.style.transition = "1s";
  element.style.transform = "rotate(${rotatePos}deg)";

  //Thank you for the help, here is my code for anyone else having
  //questions about this...
  element.onTransitionEnd.listen(transitionFinished);
}

void transitionFinished(Event e) {
  query("#text").text = "Event Finished!";
}
```

How would I then go about setting up a listen for when the transform, or transition is complete?  Or am I simply going about this the wrong way?  Basically what I ultimately want to do is play a series of transitions in sequence, and also be able to pause and continue the animation.  I thought maybe the animationEvent class might be what I'm needing to use but so far the examples I've found seem to use this with the canvas, and I'm only wanting to animate dom elements.

Answer (score 2):

use `onwebkitTransitionEnd` Event

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that before, but was having troubles making it work.  I'll edit my code above so that if anyone in the future has troubles with this.